# Display full path or namespace of .cshtml files in VS2012

Tags: tabs, visual-studio-2012

I work with a lot of cshtml files in VS 2012, and a constant irritation is not being able to see the path or namespace of the file I'm working on (barring mouse hover every time).
I've googled quite a bit, haven't found any answer, and no VS Extension seems to do it either.  Here's a screenshot of what exactly I mean (several index.cshtml, no easy way of distinguishing):

[image]

Either in a separate toolbar underneath like regular CS code files or as the tab title itself would be fine.  Does anyone know of a tool or setting for this?